# Not able to mount EFS with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ebs

I am trying to mount EFS to amazon beanstalk with EBS script. storage-efs-createfilesystem.config
But that script is not able to find an environment so below 3 lines are failing and says no such file or directory.
Code:

```
EFS_REGION=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.REGION')
EFS_MOUNT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.MOUNT_DIRECTORY')
EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.EFS_ID')
```

ERROR:

> 2020-07-22 16:51:24,595 P5115 [INFO] Command 01_mount 2020-07-22
> 16:51:24,627 P5115 [INFO] -----------------------Command
> Output----------------------- 2020-07-22 16:51:24,628 P5115 [INFO]
> /tmp/mount-efs.sh: line 3: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config: No
> such file or directory 2020-07-22 16:51:24,628 P5115 [INFO]
> /tmp/mount-efs.sh: line 4: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config: No
> such file or directory 2020-07-22 16:51:24,628 P5115 [INFO]
> /tmp/mount-efs.sh: line 5: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config: No
> such file or directory 2020-07-22 16:51:24,628 P5115 [INFO]   Mounting
> ITE EFS filesystem  to directory  ... 2020-07-22 16:51:24,628 P5115
> [INFO]    Stopping NFS ID Mapper... 2020-07-22 16:51:24,628 P5115 [INFO]
> rpc.idmapd is already stopped!

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs beacause you are using **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2) as your EB platform.

However, your script tries to use  `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config` which **works only in AL1**.

Thus you either have to modify you script to work in AL2, or use old EB platform which is based on AL1.

Comment: yes, I modified the script. Thanks for pointer

Comment: Right now, in 2022, /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config works fine in AL2 as well.